# MVC 4 Reading bytes from HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I what to read the bytes of a docx file and I have this method:

```
public ActionResult Create(Model myModel, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        {

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        byte[] bin = new byte[100]; 
                        long rdlen = 0;              
                        long totlen = fileUpload.InputStream.Length;    
                        int len;

                        while (rdlen < totlen)
                        {
                            len = fileUpload.InputStream.Read(bin, 0, 100);
                            ms.Write(bin, 0, len);
                            rdlen += len;
                        }
}
```

the total length of the file is 11338 but it only reads until 11326  then it stuck in an infinite loop because when it reaches the 11326 this `len = fileUpload.InputStream.Read(bin, 0, 100);` will only return 0 as a value. The weird thing is that if I upload a txt file it work as it should.

Thanks

Comment: can you show complete action?

Comment: the method is really long but this is the piece that it's given me trouble.

Comment: fileUpload is of what type?

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase docx file

Answer (score 1):

```
        byte[] myFile;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            httpPostedFileBase.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            myFile = memoryStream.ToArray();// or use .GetBuffer() as suggested by Morten Anderson
        }
```

Comment: This may be the right answer, but it's hard to tell why or even if it answers the OP's question without some explanation. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This works, im using it myself for images uploaded.

```
public ActionResult Create(Model myModel, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{ 
    byte[] Data = null;

    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileUpload.InputStream))
    {
        Data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(fileUpload.ContentLength);
    }
}
```